# Entity Framework 5 code first not mapping a model

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I have been working with EF5 trying to build an application and have run into a small problem.

I have created a model like

```
 public class TargetBusinessModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid BusinessId {get; set; }
    public Business Business { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
}
```

Updated the Context file

```
  public DbSet<TargetBusinessModel> TargetBusinessModels { get; set; }
```

My problem is none of the properties from Business are mapped within the database.

The Business Model I am trying to add is from another project, I am not sure if that's the reason.

I don't mind if the code first creates a separate table for my Business model or combines them together.

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `DbSet` for `Business` entities to your `DbContext` implementation:

```
public DbSet<Business> Businesses { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks lazy that was the answer :)